# Overloading of insertion operator Versus using setter function

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

In this code I am overloading >> operator to input data members of the object of the class.It can also be done using getter functions. What are the advantages of overloading >> operator compared to using setter function?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class point {
int x ,y ,z;
public:
void show(){
cout << x << y << z;
}

}

friend istream& operator >> (istream & i,point &);
};

istream& operator >> (istream & i,point &p){
i >> p.x >> p.y >> p.z;
return i;
}


int main(){
point p1,p2,p3;
cin >> p1 >> p2;//Cascading using friend function
return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can write a much more readable `i >> p.x >> p.y >> p.z;`

Comment: using an input operator or getters arent really alternatives. Setters dont allow you to e.g. read from a file. Setters allow you to set individual members, your input operator does not

Comment: Done that.I am asking when the same can be done using getter functions, why should i overload >>.

Comment: who told you that you should? You can, for example to read from a file (or any other `istream`). If you dont need that, then just dont do it. overloading an input operator and providing setters is rather orthogonal

Comment: btw I think you mean "setter" not "getter" otherwise I dont understand the question at all

Comment: Ya. My bad. I edited that.

Comment: Are there any more advantages except for reading from file that overloading of >> provides.

Comment: You know that `operator >>` and `operator <<` are actually the bit shift operators? As they are built-in for integer types only, they can be (and have been) "abused" for other purposes. The usage in `stream` is quite pretty (illustrative) but provides actually a quite different semantic than the built-ins. Following the "`stream` I/O shift" approach or defining just different semantics for other classes is on your own decision. You may do whatever the compiler accepts. Whether somebody else consider this as readable/reasonable is a fully different topic...

Answer (score 0):

*It's not an either/or situation*. Setters/Getters are a fairly useful global design feature, but you don't have to scrap them to introduce the `<<`/`>>` notation.

The `<<`/`>>` notation is (ime) mostly used with things that can be seen as streams - in particular, the standard library streams, but also with custom classes that represent some sort of flow of data.

### Advantages of `<<`/`>>`

When the objects you're using are likely to be used in this sort of context (streams of data), then overriding those operators can make a huge difference to the readability and ease of understanding of your code compared to normal getters/setters.

Also, as you show in your code, the "cascading" functionality can be a really concise way of expressing what's happening.

### Advantages of `get`/`set`

Getters/Setters are (again ime) far more common, so it's more likely someone else reading/using your code will immediately understand the point of it.

They also allow finer-grained control over *what* is being read/written. Maybe you don't want to write the entire object, but just a single member of it.

### Conclusion

Both have their uses, I'd say it's mostly contextual as to which you use. I rarely override those operators but very frequently use get/set methods - but then the code I usually write doesn't involve much input/output.